# clojure threading macro with failure form

Tags: error-handling, clojure

I have a few operations I want to thread where each can fail. I would much rather get the error as a value instead of using try-catch which breaks the flow of execution.

I can do the naive version and make my functions use nil as failure:

```
(if-let (op1 ...)
  (if-let (op2 ...)
    ...
    err1)
  err2)
```

but this is nested and makes it harder to read.

I could use `some->` which seems like the closest solution but it doesn't say what failed:

```
(if-let [res (some-> arg
                     op1
                     op2)]
  res
  somethin-failed) ;; what failed though?
```

I also looked at `->`, and `cond->` but they don't seem to help.

I know there are macros online to do these kind of things but I would much rather not add macros if something exists to solve this. Hopefully there is something of the form:

```
(some-with-err-> arg
                 op1 err1
                 op2 err2
                 ...)
```

I may be overlooking something simpler, but I can't seem to find something built-in to address this issue.

I can write a macro to do it but would rather avoid it for now.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://github.com/fmnoise/flow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built-in for this, but there are libraries for monadic error handling (e.g. [Failjure](https://github.com/adambard/failjure)) which seems like what you're looking for.

You could derive a version `some-with-err->` from the `some->` macro definition. The only practical difference is the `map` function that binds to `steps` now partitions the forms/error values, wraps `step` invocations in `try` and returns a namespaced map on failure:

```
(defmacro some-with-err->
  [expr & forms]
  {:pre [(even? (count forms))]}
  (let [g (gensym)
        steps (map (fn [[step error]]
                     `(if (or (nil? ~g) (::error ~g))
                        ~g
                        (try (-> ~g ~step)
                             (catch Exception _# {::error ~error}))))
                   (partition 2 forms))]
    `(let [~g ~expr
           ~@(interleave (repeat g) (butlast steps))]
       ~(if (empty? steps)
          g
          (last steps)))))
```

It can be used like `some->` but each form must be accompanied by an error return value:

```
(some-with-err-> 1
  (+ 1) :addition
  (/ 0) :division
  (* 2) :multiplication)
=> #:user{:error :division}

(some-with-err-> " "
  (clojure.string/trim) :trim
  (not-empty) :empty
  (str "foo") :append)
=> nil ;; from not-empty
```